# select Value in one listbox should affect all other list boxes

Tags: javascript, listbox, onchange

i have three list boxes name as state,District, and college. All list boxes contains a value as "All". if i select all in state list box the other list boxes district and college should change as "All". How to make it? i have done changes for two list boxes. i couldn't make for the third one.

```
ex :   1. State - 
                a) xxxxxxx
                b) yyyyyyy
                c) zzzzzzz
                d) All

          2. District - 
               a) aaaaaaa
               b) bbbbbbb
               c) All

          3. College - 
               a) aaaaaaa
               b) All
```

see there, if i click "All" in a state list box the District and College Should come as all.
before that i have done if i click "All" in district list box the college sholud change as "All" . How to write code in onChange??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you could do something like this:

```
<select id="state" size="3">
    <option value="0">state1</option>
    <option value="1">state2</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
</select>

<select id="district" size="3">
    <option value="0">district1</option>
    <option value="1">district9</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
</select>

<select id="collage" size="3">
    <option value="0">collage1</option>
    <option value="1">collage2</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#state').click(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'all') {
            $('#district').val('all');
            $('#collage').val('all');
        }
    });
    $('#district').click(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'all') $('#collage').val('all');
    });
</script>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/CDMWK/3/

Comment: How might you do this without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='selection1'>

....options ...

</select>

var select= document.getElementById('selection1');

select.onchange = function () {
    var index = this.selectedIndex;

    if (index == SomeValue ) {
       // do something

    }
}
```

it makes sense to use a switch statement to do different stuff depending on the item selected.

to access the value of the selected item you can use this inside the onchange:

```
...
var selectedValue = this.options[index].value; // index is the selectedIndex;
...
```

Comment: hmm thank u for ur help ibu...i have less time mr.ibu thats y i couldn't take a look ur script.surely i'll consider it when i free.